# Too many initializer values while passing boolean array as function input

Tags: arrays, c, boolean

Good day everyone. I'm working on this Game of Life problem and trying to pass an array of boolean:(Given)

```
game({0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 15, 9);
```

into the function below:(Given)

```
void game(bool cells[], int size, int num_gen)
```

However, I'm getting this error: *Too many initializer values C/C++ (146)*

I tried to play around and was able to pass in values by declaring the array in the main function:

```
int main(void) 
{
    int cells[]={0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
}
```

But this is my school assignment, so I'm not supposed to edit any given codes/inputs/functions.

I'm kinda lost now, will appreciate any inputs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *But this is my school assignment* -- What computer language is this assignment supposed to be written in?  Is it C, or is it C++?

Comment: Which part exactly are you not allowed to edit? Because you will need to change either the call or the declaration

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Technically it should be in C

Comment: @UnholySheep Both the input (test case) and game function were given. So we shouldn't modify those

Comment: So you have been given code that doesn't compile and are supposed to make it compile without changing anything? That is going to be difficult

Comment: @UnholySheep We are supposed to submit it via our course website, and it'll compile and return the results. Well, yea those were given although I'm not sure what's under the hood when it compiles, we have no access to the main function. So it's kinda difficult to code it ourselves in VScode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list of values in braces is not valid at an expression.  What you need is a **compound literal**:

```
game((bool []){0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 15, 9);
```

The syntax that looks like a cast before the braced segment gives you the type.  You can also use this syntax for a `struct` literal.

Comment: Note that this is C-only. C++ doesn't have compound literals. It's a shame that the OP has both tags.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> void game(bool cells[], int size, int num_gen)
> ```

The first parameter of your function is not an array. Sure, you declared the parameter to be an array of unspecified length, but such parameter will be adjusted to be a pointer to element of such array. A function parameter is never an array in C++.

As such, you are attempting to initialise a pointer with a brace-enclosed list of values. There are more than one value, so it's wrong (and the types of the values are also incompatible with a pointer).

You can create an array, and pass a pointer to element of that array:

```
int cells[]={0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
game(cells, std::size(cells), 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [compound literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Compound_literals) for this.

Something like

```
game((bool []){0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 15, 9);
```

Comment: Note that this is C-only. C++ doesn't have compound literals. It's a shame that the OP has both tags.

Comment: @Ruslan Oops my bad. It should be in C, but I'll also like to know what can be done if it's in C++